# Storing ambiences in to a post-prodution house library

Tags: ambiance

When adding ambiances into an library to be used in a post-production house, what is good to think about?

For example, does post houses have all sounds in a library saved at the same sample-rate and bit-depth? To make it easier to add them into a project?
Are details about whats going on in the ambiance added to the metadata? Or just type of location "busy city street"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have them all the same bit/sample(probably 48khz 24bit but might be worth checking with the post house what they'd like)

If the sounds have extra details other than the general atmos sounds (e.g. bus stopping, dog barking, helicopter overhead) then it's a good idea to put them into the meta data as well. There's some great advice on how to create awesome meta data on this site http://www.creativefieldrecording.com/

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot! It sure helped. I have recorded my atmos in 48kHz  24 bit until now so i probably wont quantize into 16 bits. And ill mention extra details in the meta. For example, if a man reads the newspaper inside a train recording i mention it. Btw, is it worth cutting these details out? Do you believe they would appreciate long raw material to cut from them selfes or finished shorter versions of clean ambiances without extra details like bus stops or helicopter overheads?

Comment: personally I'd cut out the details and use the finished shorter clips (about 2 minutes is good for an atmos if it is longer it's all good as long it's clean) If you think the details might be useful for something then keep them but have them as seperate files. It's easy to add something like a helicopter in if you want it there but it can be a pain to remove or ruin the atmos for general use if you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I will focus on getting out one clean main version without details and secondary some versions with details if I think they can be useful. Btw, are details like stereo recording technique, effects like limiter and such mentioned in the meta data?

Comment: Yep as much detail as you can in the meta data, have a look at the paul virostek site, he goes into a lot of detail about meta data.